# boost read() never returns eventhough write executed on server (ssl) boost

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, tcp

I have a server running in async and a client running in sync.

The client and server do a handshake, and then they do the SSL handshake. The client sends a message to the server, the server reads the message (and I can print it out correctly) and then the server sends back a response `boost::async_write`. The response leaves the server and the reads are being executed on the client `boost::read()` but the client never returns from the read command. Eventually the request times out and throws an exception (request timed out).

The server is asynchronous and the client is synchronous.

Please note that without SSL, everything works correctly, but with SSL the scenario above unfolds. I have viewed in Wireshark that the handshake works correctly and both the SSL and TCP handshake are correct. Plus, when the client sends the first message `boost::write()`, the server can decrypt and read it perfectly (`boost::read_async`). The server sends back the message perfectly(boost:write_async)... but the client for some reason never returns from reading!! (ONLY in the SSL case, normal TCP works correctly).

Boost version is 1.48 ... and I am truly puzzled how TCP can work fine and SSL is not working (but the as per the scenario above it has nothing to do with the encryption aspect). Is there something I have to do in boost differently than I currently have?

Comment: Is this a programming question or maybe a question to be placed at server fault?

Comment: i would assume so because the result is probably some piece of code that needs to be changed using boost?

Comment: Some piece of code such as what?

Comment: i would assume... there is something in the read function that i need to change... or possibly some type of delimiter i need to add at the end of the message? It could possibly have to do with one way is synchronous and the other is asynchronous (with ssl?)

Comment: Since you're using encrypted streams, they'll be buffering at least up until another block, likely 16 bytes but is encryption algorithm dependant. Try flushing the stream, on both ends, after your writes.

Comment: ok so i have a do/while loop. in thedo it is calling boost::asio::read and passing in the socket object, boost::asio::buffer(size),boost:asio::transfer_all(),error_code) . After that i do a printf on the character array and i see the data has been received correctly! hooray! BUT... the function is never returning and eventually times out. Why would this work perfectly fine in a tcp situation but when i am using TLS for some reason this loop never exits (eventhough the data i wanted was received. Should i be appending something else to my sending message (or do something else in receiving)?

Comment: The loop parameters are basically while(count < size) (size being the size of the mutable buffer being passed in and count += boost::asio::read(

Comment: another update: so it seems that the transfer_all() function is not returning. It eventually times out and sends that error code. is there a recommended way of flushing out the stream on the send side ( i have mutable buffers being passed in...

Comment: also.. i am using boost::asio:async_write and boost::asio::write(socket, buff, transfer_all(), ec) is this not the correct way to send a socket. (i have never had a problem with  a tcp socket)

Comment: another update. So it looks like the header i am sending and data is correct. but the header i am receiving is wrong! the length field looks corrupted. Would this be something with padding possibly(or maybe flushing out the streams)?

Comment: Well.  You do a `read` without a stopping condition. You can expect it to hang until the connection is closed. See also [`Connection: close`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: the issue was for some reason the header of one of the messages i was passing in was out of scope. Declearing a header on the stack of a function, and then passing that into an async Send will NOT guarantee the memory of that header has been passed entirely into the function. The header has to have a more persistent scope (such as a heap, member variable etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was for some reason the header of one of the messages i was passing in was out of scope. Declaring a header on the stack of a function, and then passing that into an async Send will NOT guarantee the memory of that header has been passed entirely into the function. The header has to have a more persistent scope (such as a heap, member variable etc) in the async case.